# illegal path error created due to a "comma" in jmeter

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

How to solve illegal path error created due to a "comma"

same rest url displays in webpage but in jmeter throws illegal path error

`java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 112:`

Comment: Did you tried encoding "comma"?

Comment: Replacing comma with %2C Worked perfectly.Thanks

Comment: Great mate! Glad to help!

Comment: @Ivan, why do you answer in comments ? it would be better to answer in answer field so that question is marked as answered and you get rewarded as a bonus :) ?

Answer (score 2):

URL paths containing special signs need to be encoded. So your best option is to encode whole path and ensure yourself that no exceptions like that one will be thrown.

There are many ways to achieve this. For example, you could use [JMeter function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) or do it manually in one [Beanshell Pre-processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor).

Comment: It is for sure, but it depends how do you want to achieve this and for what reason.